# Complex infinite sum convergence problem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose that the complex infinite sum $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}Z_n$ converges.

Define $A \subset \mathbb{C}$ by

$A=\{{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid\exists f:\mathbb{N}\underset{on}{\overset{1-1}{\rightarrow}}\mathbb{N},z= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Z_{f(n)}}\}$

Prove that $A=\mathbb{C}$ or that  $\exists a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $A = \{a+tb \mid t\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

--edit-- in bounty message I mean solution of the problem.

Comment: Please don't just dump undigested problems here with no indication that you have put any thought into them. Why are you interested in this problem? What thoughts do you have about it? What pertinent facts do you already know? Where are you getting stuck? Engage with us, so we can write more useful answers.

Comment: This is a very uncommon task, I completelly have no idea how to start. I need hints how to start thinking on it.

Comment: When you have no idea how to start on something, it's often helpful to construct some examples, and play with them. Know any such convergent series? Pick one, and see what happens when you apply such an $f$ to it. Do a few examples, see if you can work out what's going on. Also, see if there's anything like this in whatever text or notes you're learning from.

Comment: First, it seems to be that you meant "prove that $\,A=\Bbb C\,$" . Also, in the definition of $\,A\,$ , what exactly is that $\,z_{f(n)}\,$ ? Are these the same as $\,Z_n\,$ in the question's first line? You must be at least a 2nd-3rd year student, you must be way more careful to post your questions and as a mathematics student you should know that there's already *no one freaking thing at all* that you're asked to do and you "have completely no idea how to start". That's fine for lazy or completely resourceless high school students, not of advanced undergraduate ones.

Comment: That one is not a homework, it's an old homework for extended level students. Just I want to know, how it should be done, and still don't know how to start.

Comment: Steve, Gerry gave you some very good advice on how to start.

Comment: @Steve, you might start by explaining what $z_{f(n)}$ means.  Or do you mean $Z_{f(n)}$?

Comment: $Z_n$ is a serie. $Z_{f(n)}$ is a serie with indexes f(0), f(1), ...

Comment: @Steve: You still haven't explained what $z_{f(n)}$ is. From what you write, it seems that you actually wanted this to be $Z_{f(n)}$, as rlgordonma had guessed.

Comment: I don't understand why there are four close votes for this question. Two are for the reason "not constructive" and two for "not a real question". As annoying as carelessly typed questions with imperatives and no work shown are, closing them seems like a significant overreaction to me. It's perfectly clear (at least to me) what this question is asking, and it's a perfectly legitimate mathematical question. No-one has to answer it in its present sloppy form if they don't want to, but that's not a reason for closing it.

Comment: Yes, that is a big Z. Sorry for that, and please don't close my question.

Comment: @Steve - what is the source of the problem?

Comment: @nbubis Old homework, don't know what is primary source.

Comment: If it's false, please just prove it, there are (very rare) mistakes in tasks.

Comment: @did: The result is stated in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem#Generalization). Your counterexample isn't one because the case of an unconditionally convergent series is covered by $b=0$.

Comment: @Steve: It still says $A=C$, but no set $C$ has been introduced. From the Wikipedia article, it seems that you mean $\mathbb C$, as DonAntonio had already guessed some time ago? Please make more of an effort to take comments into account; the question could have been cleaned up earlier if you had.

Comment: Ok. Done. Sorry.

Comment: @Steve: One more minor point: The vertical bar `|` is treated as a norm bar and gets the wrong spacing if you use it as a binary operator or seperator; the command for such purposes is `\mid`.

Comment: I've fixed this issue

Comment: You didn't, you fixed one instance of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle \sum_{n \geq 1} X_n$ be a conditionally convergent series in the $d$-dimensional real Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. Then the set $Y$ of all possible sums of rearrangments of this series is an affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. When $d=1$, this is the well know Riemann rearrangement theorem and the proof is not very difficult.

Addendum: A good reference on this is the following: 
The Remarkable Theorem of Levy and Steinitz,
Peter Rosenthal,
The American Mathematical Monthly,
Vol. 94, No. 4 (Apr., 1987), pp. 342-351

I also realized that you do not need conditional convergence because of the way you stated your conclusion (b = 0 covers absolutely convergent case). So I removed that trivial remark.

Comment: The cited article can be found [on JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdfplus/2323094.pdf).